# React Component only updates once

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Consider the following React Native  code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View, StyleSheet, Button} from 'react-native';

export default class Target extends React.Component {

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state ={ isLoading: true};
        this.hitData = this.props.hitData;
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        for(let i of Object.keys(this.hitData)){
            if(this.hitData[i] === 0){
                this.hitData[i] = '---'
            }
        }
        this.setState({
            prop1: this.hitData['prop1'],
            prop2: this.hitData['prop2'],
            prop3: this.hitData['prop3'],
            prop4: this.hitData['prop4'],
            prop5: this.hitData['prop5'],
            isLoading: false
        });
        this.onPress = this.onPress.bind(this);

    }


    componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {

       // console.log(prevProps)
       if(this.props.hitData !== prevProps.hitData){
           console.log("Component "+  this.state.mac + " got new props!");
           this.hitData = this.props.hitData;

           this.setState((state, props) =>{
               let newState = {};
               for(let i of Object.keys(props.hitData))
               {
                   if(state[i] !== props.hitData[i])
                   {
                       console.log(i + " is different!");
                       newState[i] = props.hitData[i]
                   }
               }
               return newState
           });
       }
    }


    onPress(txt) {
        console.log(txt);
    }




    render(){
        return(
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <View style={{flex: 1, flexDirection: 'row'}}>
                    <View style={{borderWidth: 2.5, borderColor: '#00FF00',width: '50%'}}>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 19, fontWeight: 'bold'}}>{this.state.prop1}</Text>
                        <Text style={{fontSize: 16}} numberOfLines={1}>{this.state.prop2}</Text>
                    </View>
                    <View>
                        <Text>{"Prop3: " + this.state.prop3}</Text>
                        <Text>{"Prop4: " + this.state.prop4}</Text>
                        <Text>{"Prop5: " + this.state.prop4}</Text>
                    </View>
                </View>

                <Button key={this.hitData[0]} title={"BUTTON"} onPress={() => this.onPress(this.hitData[0])}/>

            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        borderRadius: 4,
        borderWidth: 2.5,
        height: 100,
        marginBottom: 5,
        overflow: 'hidden'
    }
});
```

This is the code for a React Native component. The component takes in information received from an EventSource in the parent element. The aim is to update the fields containing `Prop[3-5]`based on data from future events.

In the parent component I have a property per item on `state` and am defining each element like: 
`const targetList = this.state.filterKeys.map((item) =>
            <Target key={item} hitData={this.state[item]['lastHit']}/>`

In my Event handler I can then do:

`this.setState({
                [id]: hitIntermediate
            })`

to send new props to each child component.

In my child component I do see the new props arriving, but after the first update the child stops updating. It does not matter how many events I send, after the first update has been received no further updates are displayed.

The strange part is if I query `this.state` in the child component, I do see that the state reflects the data from the new event, but the display does not change.

Am I completely misunderstanding something here. Essentially what I am wanting to do is to do the equivalent of setting `.innerHTML` on the `<Text>` tags containing the various pieces of data, but all my updates seem to get ignored after the first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this on my own.

As it turns out, the way I was getting events into my component was silly.
I changed it so instead of maintaining a hugely complex state out in the main component, I how just pass in the EventSource and define an eventhandler inside each child component.

Now I am seeing updates in close to real-time. I would still like to improve re-render performance a little bit, but overall the issue I was having is resolved.

Now a quick bonus question: why is it I seem to see (slightly) faster performance if I have the react-devtools running?

Comment: I don't know which browser you're using and how it handles this, but if the tab you're using for debugging isn't focused (it's a background tab) because of the way e.g. Chrome handles background tabs, it's going to take a bit longer to update